# Лексическая функция

Tags: смысл

Объясните, пожалуйста, что такое лексическая функция. И приведите примеры, какие они бывают, помимо Magn (высокая степень проявленности, "проливной дождь", "круглый дурак").

Answer (score 1):

Это понятие, введённое лингвистами [Мельчуком](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%87%D1%83%D0%BA,_%D0%98%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8C_%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) и [Жолковским](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9,_%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) в рамках их теории [«Смысл — текст»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%C2%AB%D0%A1%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB_%E2%80%94_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%C2%BB).

В широком смысле, *лексическая функция* это правило, показывающее связь между лексемами языка. К примеру вы можете задаться вопросом: «как усилить лексему?». Ответ на этот вопрос даёт функция `Magn`, которую вы упомянули:

- `Magn(«терпение») = «ангельское»`
- `Magn(«чистый») = «кристально», «как стеклышко»`
- `Magn(«смеяться») = «до слез», «до упаду»`
- …

Конечно, это не *функция* в математическом смысле слова, а *отношение*, поскольку одному входу она может сопоставлять не один, а несколько разных выходов. Кроме того, обычно ограничиваются каким-то фиксированным небольшим набором лексем, поскольку язык очень богат, и перечислить их все невозможно.

В качестве примера другой лексической функции можно привести, например, функцию `Son`, отвечающую на вопрос «какой характерный звук издает?»:

- `Son(«кот») = «мяукать»`
- `Son(«листья») = «шелестеть»`
- `Son(«половица») = «скрипеть»`
- …

Или вот функция `S_res` — результат действия или ситуации:

- `S_res(«изучать») = «знание», «навык», «умение»`
- `S_res(«взрыв») = «взрывная волна»`
- `S_res(«рисовать») = «картина», «рисунок»`
- …

Больше примеров лексических функций есть в [посвященной им статье в английской Википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_function#Standard_Lexical_Functions).